# Validity via comparing strings while iterating through an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison, equals

Sorry if my question seems a little vague.

Basically what I am trying to do is error check using string comparison on a constructor object, which is stored in an array. I think I have the right idea: (*Count is a static int that iterates whenever an employee is added in another method*)

```
public static void updateTitle(Employee searchArray[]) {
    String searchID;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Employee ID for manipulation: ");
    searchID = input.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String arrayID = searchArray[i].getEmployeeNumber();

        if (searchID.equals(arrayID) == true) {

            System.out.println("Employee: " + searchID + " found!");
            System.out.println("Employee " + searchID
                    + "'s current title is: "
                    + searchArray[i].getEmployeeTitle());
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out
                    .println("Would you like to change this employees title? (Y/N)");
            System.out.println(" ");
            String answer = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if (answer.equals("Y")) {
                System.out.println("Enter new title: ");
                String newTitle = input.nextLine();
                searchArray[i].setEmployeeTitle(newTitle);
                searchArray[i].updateTitle(newTitle);
            }
            if (answer.equals("N")) {
                break;
            }
        } else if (searchID.equals(arrayID) == false) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid ID!");
        }

    }
}
```

This successfully error checks, however because it is iterating through the array, it will display an error message before a validation message if the array element is > 0 and is found in the array. Is there any way to analyse every element of the array and produce the error message if and only if the ID is not found in *any* elements?

Comment: You could save it to a variable and do a conditional check at the end against the variable.

Comment: The expression ```searchID.equals(arrayID) == true``` is the same as ```searchID.equals(arrayID)```, which is of better style.

Comment: I think I have solved my own problem. I created a boolean value that checks whether it is found or not, and if it's not found, outside the For loop it will display an error message. That way it's not doubling up.

Answer (score 1):

you definitely should read a book how to program in Java.
All code below should be rewritten, but I leave it for understanding the error.

```
public static void updateTitle(Employee searchArray[]) {
    String searchID;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Employee ID for manipulation: ");
    searchID = input.nextLine();

    Employee found = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
        String arrayID = searchArray[i].getEmployeeNumber();

        if (searchID.equals(arrayID)) {
            found = searchArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found != null) {
        System.out.println("Employee: " + searchID + " found!");
        System.out.println("Employee " + searchID + "'s current title is: " + found.getEmployeeTitle());
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Would you like to change this employees title? (Y/N)");
        System.out.println(" ");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter new title: ");
            String newTitle = input.nextLine();
            found.setEmployeeTitle(newTitle);
            found.updateTitle(newTitle);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid ID!");
    }
}
```